# How do i retrieve my ratings from my database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

how do i get to retrieve my ratings something like this "['G','PG','PG-13','R']" from my database through my class method in my Movie class? My database contains a list of Movies table in which the row entails "title","ratings","description","release date".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the fact you've tagged rails and listed what sounds like a table structure I'm going to assume you're using Rails' ORM ActiveRecord with postgresql database right? If so, you could access your ratings by using the command `Movie.pluck(:ratings)`. This should grab all the inserts in your ratings column for your Movies table and return an array of them. You will need to implement this in one of your MoviesController actions.

Comment: Yeah. That actually worked but i got this result ["G", "R", "R", "PG-13", "PG-13", "R", "G", "PG", "PG", "G"].. but it's not meant to repeat a particular rating twice or more. how can i go about it?

Comment: I imagine `Movie.pluck(:ratings).uniq` should work so it reduces your array to unique elements.

Answer (score 3):

To get ratings of all movies in a single array like you mentioned you simply use:

```
Movie.pluck(:ratings) #assuming column name ratings
```

This will give results like

```
['G','PG','PG-13','R']
```

If you also want to know that which movie has which ratings then, you can modify the code to following:

```
Movie.pluck(:id, :ratings)
```

Its result will be something like:

```
[[1,"PG"], [2,"PG-13"], [3,"G"]]
```

For more information visit this link

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck

Answer (score 0):

If you Ratings are stored in an Array then you would had to write a function to separate all the following: `"['']"`. It would be much simple to create an enum or give you rating an ID so when you post a movie and want to give it a rating you can call it by calling its ID or enum value.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this documentation about getting specific columns. In particular de `pluck` method.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck

So, you can do something like:

```
Movie.pluck(:ratings)
```

Other option is use a normal "query" structure:

```
@movies = Movie.select('ratings').where(...#some condition)
```